# Unity2D: How do I regenerate player's health after timer countdown is at 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer

I have a script that regenerates player's health after 5 seconds:

```
  float counter;

    void  Update (){
          counter += Time.deltaTime;
           if(counter > 30minutes){
              curHealth++;
                counter = 0.0f; }
              if(curHealth > 5)
                 curHealth = 5;
                 }
```

Which is attach to my player's health script. I want to start regenerating my player health back when timer is at 0. But I don't know how.
This is my player health script:

```
//Stats
public int curHealth;
public int maxHealth = 3;
public Collider2D col;
public PlayerHealth playerhealthRef;
public TimeManager countDownTimer;
float counter;
public Animator anima; // drag the panel in here again
private UI_ManagerScripts UIM;
DateTime currentDate;
DateTime oldDate;

private GenerateEnemy generateEnemy = null;


void Start ()
{
    curHealth = maxHealth;
    currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    if (countDownTimer != null)
    {
        // countDownTimer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        countDownTimer.Enable(false);
    }
    if (GameObject.Find("Spawner"))
    {
        generateEnemy = GameObject.Find("Spawner").GetComponent<GenerateEnemy>();
    }
}


void Update ()
{
    counter += Time.deltaTime;
    if (curHealth > maxHealth) {
        curHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    if ((curHealth <= 0) && (!countDownTimer.gameObject.activeSelf)) {

        Die ();
    }
    if(counter > 5)
    {
        curHealth++;
        counter = 0.0f; 
    }
    if(curHealth > 3)
        curHealth = 3;
}


void Awake()
{
    UIM = GameObject.Find ("UIManager").GetComponent<UI_ManagerScripts> ();
}

void Die() {
    UIM.EnableBoolAnimator(anima);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RemainingLives", curHealth);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();

    if (generateEnemy != null)
    {
        generateEnemy.DestroyAllBlobs();
    }
    if (countDownTimer != null)
    {
        countDownTimer.Enable(true);
    }
}   
public void Damage(int dmg)
{
    curHealth -= dmg;
}
 }
```

And this is my Timer countdown script:

```
public Text timer;
int minutes = 1;
int seconds = 0;
float miliseconds = 0;

[Range(1, 59)]
public int defaultStartMinutes = 1;
public bool allowTimerRestart = false;
public bool useElapsedTime = true;

private int savedSeconds = -1;
private bool resetTimer = false;

private DateTime centuryBegin = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1);

private float tickPerSecond = 10000000.0f;

public void Enable (bool enable)
{
    gameObject.SetActive(enable);
    ResetTime(); // force the timer to restart
}

void Awake ()
{
    minutes = defaultStartMinutes;
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("TimeOnExit"))
    {
        miliseconds = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeOnExit");
        savedSeconds = (int)miliseconds;

        if (useElapsedTime && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("CurrentTime"))
        {
            int elapsedTicks = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks / tickPerSecond);
            int ct = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentTime", elapsedTicks);
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("CurrentTime");
            elapsedTicks -= ct;
            if (elapsedTicks < miliseconds)
            {
                miliseconds -= elapsedTicks;
            }
            else
            {
                miliseconds = 0;
            }
        }

        minutes = (int)miliseconds / 60;
        miliseconds -= (minutes * 60);

        seconds = (int)miliseconds;
        miliseconds -= seconds;

        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("TimeOnExit");

    }
    savedSeconds = 0;
}

public void Update()
{
    // count down in seconds
    miliseconds += Time.deltaTime;
    if (resetTimer)
    {
        ResetTime();
    }
    if (miliseconds >= 1.0f)
    {
        miliseconds -= 1.0f;
        if ((seconds > 0) || (minutes > 0))
        {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds < 0)
            {
                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resetTimer = allowTimerRestart;
        }
    }

    if (seconds != savedSeconds)
    {
        //  Show current time
        timer.text = string.Format("{0}:{1:D2}", minutes, seconds);
        savedSeconds = seconds;
    }
}

void ResetTime()
{
    minutes = defaultStartMinutes;
    seconds = 0;
    savedSeconds = 0;
    miliseconds = 1.0f - Time.deltaTime;
    resetTimer = false;
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    int numSeconds = ((minutes * 60) + seconds);
    if (numSeconds > 0)
    {
        miliseconds += numSeconds;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeOnExit", miliseconds);

        if (useElapsedTime)
        {
            int elapsedTicks = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks / tickPerSecond);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentTime", elapsedTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you :)

**Second edit**
 I tried doing this in my update file:

```
   if (countDownTimer = true)
    {
        if(counter > 5)
        {
            curHealth++;
            counter = 0.0f; 
        }
        if(curHealth > 3)
            curHealth = 3;
    }
```

But I got this error: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to`TimeManager'.

I just wasn't sure of how to go about doing this.?

Comment: Where *exactly* in your attempt to implement it are you having the problem?

Comment: Please look at my edited question above

Comment: `if (countDownTimer = true)` is an error. Use `if (countDownTimer)` for true and `if(!countDownTimer)` for false. Or you can use `if(countDownTimer == true)`

Answer (score 1):

According to your second edit line 1

```
 if (countDownTimer = true)
```

should be

```
if(countDownTimer)
```

as = operator is only to give a value, and for comparison you use ==, or, if the variable is bool, simply if(var) or if(!var)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is useless.

You can use WaitForSeconds(just google it) or you can add LeanTween to your project and use

```
LeanTweed.DeayedCall(5f, ()=>{ /*code that will be runned after 5 sec will pass*/});
```

I prefer to use LeanTween.